# While saving mp3 files from Google TTS generates mp3 file having 302 redirection

Tags: php, text-to-speech, voice

While saving mp3 files from Google TTS, it generates mp3 file having 302 redirection.

My Code is :

```php
$text = "This is sameer kalia.";
$text = urlencode($text);
$url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=$text";
$file = "curl.mp3";
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$output=curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$fp= fopen($file,"wb");
fwrite($fp,$output);
fclose($fp);
```

and it generates file "curl.mp3" having following code in side this file :

```html
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://ipv4.google.com/sorry/IndexRedirect?continue=http://translate.google.com/translate_tts%3Ftl%3Den%26q%3DThis%2Bis%2Bsameer%2Bkalia.&amp;q=CGMSBHnxe0oY_KD7rgUiGQDxp4NLy6TiN5I9UQ6rQvnQPe4DphVlkfY">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google has stopped allowing free usage of the private and undocumented TTS web API for everyone.  Any call to it now takes you to a captcha screen.  They started doing it at the end of July 2015.